# how to update multiple gadgets (all bar charts) with live data at same time

Tags: angular, websocket, ngx-charts

---

I want to display live data in multiple bar graph but only last graph is updated and taking the data of all graphs (using angular 7)

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't post any of your code?

Comment: The description is very abstract , by what i can understand this could help!
Store data in a service and then use observables to update data in all chart components